# Creating zip of multiple files and download in laravel

Tags: laravel

i am using the following codes to make zip and allow user to download the zip

but its not working.it shows the error as ZipArchive::close(): Read error: Bad file descriptor.What might be the problem?i am working with laravel.

```php
public function downloadposts(int $id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);


    // Define Dir Folder
    $public_dir = public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads/post/zip';
    $file_path = public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads/post';
    // Zip File Name
    $zipFileName = $post->post_title . '.zip';
    // Create ZipArchive Obj
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open($public_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
        // Add File in ZipArchive
        foreach ($post->PostDetails as $postdetails) {
            $zip->addFile($file_path, $postdetails->file_name);
        }
        // Close ZipArchive
        $zip->close();
    }
    // Set Header
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
    ];
    $filetopath = $public_dir . '/' . $zipFileName;
    dd($filetopath);
    // Create Download Response
    if (file_exists($filetopath)) {
        return response()->download($filetopath, $zipFileName, $headers);
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Yeahh..i have solved the problem.in addFile($filepath,$filename) the $filepath was incorrect. Actually i gave the directory path not the correct file path.S o i change it to

Comment: $zip->addFile(public_path().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$postdetails->file_name,$postdetails->file_name);

Comment: $zipFileName = $post->post_title . ".zip"; (dont use single quotes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only pure php code.

```php
public function makeZipWithFiles(string $zipPathAndName, array $filesAndPaths): void {
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $tempFile = tmpfile();
    $tempFileUri = stream_get_meta_data($tempFile)['uri'];

    if ($zip->open($tempFileUri, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
        echo 'Could not open ZIP file.';
        return;
    }

    // Add File in ZipArchive
    foreach($filesAndPaths as $file)
    {
        if (! $zip->addFile($file, basename($file))) {
            echo 'Could not add file to ZIP: ' . $file;
        }
    }
    // Close ZipArchive
    $zip->close();

    echo 'Path:' . $zipPathAndName;
    rename($tempFileUri, $zipPathAndName);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

### For Laravel **7.29.3** PHP **7.4.11**

Create a GET route in `api.php`

```
Route::get('/downloadZip','ZipController@download')->name('download');
```

---

Create controller `ZipController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use File;

class ZipController extends Controller
{
    public function download(Request $request)
    {
        $zip = new \ZipArchive();
        $fileName = 'zipFile.zip';
        if ($zip->open(public_path($fileName), \ZipArchive::CREATE)== TRUE)
        {
            $files = File::files(public_path('myFiles'));
            foreach ($files as $key => $value){
                $relativeName = basename($value);
                $zip->addFile($value, $relativeName);
            }
            $zip->close();
        }

        return response()->download(public_path($fileName));
    }
}
```

---

In the `public` folder make sure you have a folder `myFiles`. This snippet will get every file within the folder, create a new zip file and put within the `public` folder, then when route is called it returns the zip file created.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\ImgUpload;
use ZipArchive;
use File;
class UserController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Function to get all images from DB
 */
public function downloadZip()
{
  $data = ImgUpload::all();
  foreach($data as $key => $value)
  {
    $imgarr[] = "storage/image". '/' . $value->image;
  }

  $ziplink = $this->converToZip($imgarr);
  return $ziplink;


}
/**
 * Function to covert all DB files to Zip
 */
public function converToZip($imgarr)
{
            $zip = new ZipArchive;
            $storage_path = 'storage/image';
            $timeName = time();
            $zipFileName = $storage_path . '/' . $timeName . '.zip';
            $zipPath = asset($zipFileName);
            if ($zip->open(($zipFileName), ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {
                foreach ($imgarr as $relativName) {
                    $zip->addFile($relativName,"/".$timeName."/".basename($relativName));
                }
                $zip->close();

                if ($zip->open($zipFileName) === true) {
                    return $zipPath;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
}

}
```

you can refer [this link](https://www.studywithkishan.online/2021/01/create-zip-file-and-download-in-laravel.html) for more information

Comment: this works for me in laravel 8

Answer (score 2):

The question got answer, but I am posting this solution for those who wants to download dynamically zip some (based on id) files from the same folder, I hope it might help them that how to create dynamic zip file of multiple files/images affiliated with some id.
I would be taking example of multiple images. You can do the same for files.

[image]

Assuming the above table the autos_id is foreign key and based on the autos_id, there are multiple images store in the database.

To make zip file of it I will do the following:

```
public function downloadZip($id)
    {

$data = AutoImage::where('autos_id',$id)->get();

$imgarr=[];
foreach($data as $data){

    $file =  storage_path() . '/app/public/autoImages/'.$data->image_name;

    if(\File::exists(public_path('storage/autoImages/'.$data->image_name))){
       $imgarr[]= public_path('storage/autoImages/'.$data->image_name);
      }

}

        $zip = new ZipArchive;

        $fileName = 'AutoImages.zip';
    /*OVERWRITE will not make a different zip file on server but it will 
replace the one which is in the server, this approach will help you to not 
make multiple zip files, if you want to creat new you can do it with unique
 name of the zip file and adding CREATE instead of OVERWRITE.*/
        if ($zip->open(public_path($fileName), ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) === TRUE)
        {
            $files = $imgarr; //passing the above array

            foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
                $relativeNameInZipFile = basename($value);
                $zip->addFile($value, $relativeNameInZipFile);
            }

            $zip->close();
        }

        return response()->download(public_path($fileName));
    }
```

Note: for file storage I used storage and then made a link symlink for storing files.

For further info of file storage: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem

Comment: Good Work, it's helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use [Zipper](https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper) package

Try below code for creating zip of multiple files :

```
public function downloadZip($id)
    {
        $headers = ["Content-Type"=>"application/zip"];
        $fileName = $id.".zip"; // name of zip
        Zipper::make(public_path('/documents/'.$id.'.zip')) //file path for zip file
                ->add(public_path()."/documents/".$id.'/')->close(); //files to be zipped

        return response()
        ->download(public_path('/documents/'.$fileName),$fileName, $headers);
    }
```

Comment: Thanku for your advice

Comment: For anyone reading this today: the Zipper package is archived and not actively maintained anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, multiple files zip and download.

```
public function download_attachment($ticket_no)
{
    $zip = new \ZipArchive();
    $fileName = $ticket_no.'.zip';
    if ($zip->open(public_path($fileName), \ZipArchive::CREATE)== TRUE)
    {
        $files = File::files(public_path('uploads/tickets/' . $ticket_no));
        foreach ($files as $key => $value){
            $relativeName = basename($value);
            $zip->addFile($value, $relativeName);
        }
        $zip->close();
    }

    return response()->download(public_path($fileName));
}
```