# I want to Download multiple images as a zip file using laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner at laravel and I want to downloads multiple images as a zip file using laravel but I do not have an idea how can I do that please help me thanks.

**InboxController**

```
 public function dowloads($id)
    {
        $clientfiles = Inbox::where('id', $id)->first();

        dd($clientfiles->file);
        // "["phpIgRq3Q.jpg","phpe6b34M.jpg","phpnPGN2M.png","php8CQh5P.jpg"]"

        $files =config('yourstitchart.file_url');
       // $files = "http://localhost/yourstitchart.com/web/public/uploads/images/"  
    }
```

**HTML view**

```
    <a  href="{{ route('download.inbox',$digitizingInbox->id) }}"  class="download 
          btn btn-warning">Download
     </a>
```

**Route**

```
  Route::get('downloads/{id}/files','DigitizingInboxController@dowloads')->name('download.inbox');
```

Comment: Use this function given in link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873115/creating-zip-of-multiple-files-and-download-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Chumper/Zipper package to make zip files. It is used by many developers. check [here](https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper)

You can try it like:

```
$zipper = Zipper::make(public_path('/documents/deals.zip'));
$clientfiles = Inbox::where('id', $id)->first();
foreach ($clientfiles->file as $file) {
    $zipper->add(public_path($file)); // update it by your path
}
$zipper->close();
return response()
    ->download(
        public_path('/temporary_files/' . "deals.zip"),
        "deals.zip", 
        ["Content-Type" => "application/zip"]
    );
```

Comment: SIr can you guide me a/c to my code thanks.

Comment: With reference to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54922574/download-multiple-uploaded-files-in-laravel